# jQuery send Enter Key to a search field

Tags: jquery, events, datatables

Hi I have a Datatable and a Side Bar which looks like this

[image]

My function is when I clicked into one of those `li` elements \, example, `Approved` then it will appended in the Search box of the Datatable. I have it working already. But my problem is that when there's a text on the Search box, Datatables should automatically search based on that input but in my scenario it's not. Unless you manually hit the Enter key while pointing your cursor in the search box.

So what I did is add a code that will send an Enter Keypress event on that search box so When I append the `Approved` then next is it will send the Enter Key event to the search box so that I don't need to manually hit enter but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
$("li#approved_filter").on("click", function(){
    $(".input-sm").val("Approved");
    $(".input-sm").focus().trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 13 });
});
```

Comment: Faking the return key event is a bit hacky. Why not just use the built in [fnFilter](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnFilter) funciton?

Comment: Is search input in form?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't know that I could do that. It's working now. Thanks :) Should you change your comment to answer I'll select it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faking the return key event is a bit hacky. Instead you could use the built in [fnFilter](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnFilter) function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    // Sometime later - filter...
    oTable.fnFilter('test string');
});
```

In your case this would be:

```
$("li#approved_filter").on("click", function() {
    $(".input-sm").val("Approved");
    oTable.fnFilter('Approved');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect.